# Maximise the sum of one array while keeping the sum of corresponding elements of other array less than k

Tags: arrays, algorithm, language-agnostic

I have two arrays, i have to choose some elements from the first array so that their sum is maximised while the sum of the corresponding elements of second array is less than k.

I can think of a recursive solution till now, i need an iterative solution.

example :

array 1 : 2 2 5 4 3 6 10

array 2 : 4 3 2 5 4 10 7 and k = 15

all the numbers are positive.

Comment: in your case, what's the answer?

Comment: i'll choose 10, 4 and 5 from the first array so that the sum of corresponding elements in the second array is 14.

Comment: Isn't this the knapsack problem?

Comment: @user1990169 Totally agree:)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose each array has n elements. One solution is to try all possible combinations of the n elements, which means time complexity is `O(2^n)`.

While use dynamic programming can achieve `O(n*k)` time complexity:

`dp[i][j] = x` means for the first i elements, select some elements from array 2, and the sum of selected elements of array 2 is j (0 <= j < k), the max sum of corresponding selected elements of array 1 is x. Then we want `dp[n][j]` (0 <= j < k) maximum.

The state transition equation is to try whether the ith element of array 2 is selected. If not selected, `dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j]`; If selected, dp[i][j] can be `max(dp[i-1][j], dp[i-1][j-b[i]] + a[i])`, here b[i] <= j < k.

```
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<k;j++) {
            dp[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    if(b[1] < k) {
        dp[1][b[0]] = a[0];
    }
    for(i=2;i<=n;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<k;j++) {
            dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j];
            if(j >= b[i] && dp[i-1][j - b[i]] + a[i] > dp[i][j]) {
                dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j - b[i]] + a[i];
            }
        }
    }
```

The answer is `max(d[[n][j]), 0 <= j< k`.

Please select different algorithm according to how big `n` and `k` are.

Answer (score 0):

Each element of the array can be either present of missing thus resulting in `2^N` combinations to be evaluated. You can, for example, generate numbers from `0` to `2^N-1` and use their individual bits as indicators of such presence/absence.

The whole solution can be found by this Python one-liner (split into three lines here):

```py
import itertools

a1 = [2, 2, 5, 4, 3, 6, 10]
a2 = [4, 3, 2, 5, 4, 10, 7]
k = 15

print sorted((sum(itertools.compress(a1, s)), s)
    for s in itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=len(a1))
        if sum(itertools.compress(a2, s)) < k)[-1][1]
```